# Plotting multiple different plots using same container and different data in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have an xrange graph and i want to plot a lengend on top what each color signifies in the same line. The xrange graph should be below the said legend.
The legend has 4 values (eg. val1,val2,val3,val4 ).
So the structure must be something like this:

() val1 () val2 () val3 () val4

[

X range graph

].

() denotes colored circles, diff for each val.
[ ] denotes the xrange graph.

The x-axis of the x range graph is on top. So the legend must be above that.

I tried creating legends using the one in a bar graph since it automatically uses circles and label formatter for the text using html. But functions() cant be used since the platform i'm using doesn't support it. Am currently trying to create legend with a bubble chart (for the circles) and a heat map (for the text) but it appears in the canvas of the xrange graph and is getting hard to format. I used plot options to add the bubble chart and the heat map.

Comment: Hi @Pranav Vasist 1DS19CS734, Could you explain your problem more precisely? I've prepared a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2mjf13kL/ which should present your wanted result. Can you refer to that?

Comment: This is exactly what i need, just that the legend is not related to the xrange graph. i.e it should be completely independent of the xrange graph. Thanks a ton.

Comment: In this case, you can for example add mocked column series with defined names. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o8p4fgrb/